# WebApi GET is not hit in Postman but works in chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

I'm having trouble with setting up a simple WebApi. I believe the problem is with my webApi code. When I hit this endpoint in Chrome, I am able to see the message "WebApi is up and running". With my HttpClient that resides in a console application, I do not get a response. Then I tried with Postman and I also do not get a response. What is wrong with my WebApi?

In the HttpClient, I have added two Nuget Packages: Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client and Newtonsoft.Json

Both The httpClient and WebApi are written in .Core 3.1

**Code in WebAPI:**

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public TestController ()
    {
    }

    [HttpGet("api/test")]
    public string Get()
    {
      return "WebApi is up and running.";
    } 
}
```

**Code in HttpClient**

```
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            UseDefaultCredentials = true
        });
        // Update port # in the following line.
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:44335/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        HttpResponseMessage get = await client.GetAsync("api/test");
```

Comment: You need to do `var data = await get.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();` to get the actual content returned from web API

Comment: HttpResponseMessage get = await client.GetAsync("api/test");
Does not return anything and there is an exception waiting. It never gets to the other line you suggested.

Comment: Then to might want to use try..catch and catch the exception and share the exception message here... If there is an exception happening then we need to know it.

Answer (score 0):

As **@Chetan Ranpariya** mentioned in the comment section, you need to use [`Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcontent.readasstringasync) to get result asynchronously:

```
HttpResponseMessage get = await client.GetAsync("api/test");
var content = await get.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```